# How are the batches iterated in the PTB LSTM example of Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently trying to understand the LSTM tutorial from Tensorflow and have a question about the code of https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py.
In the function `run_epoch()` these lines run an epoch, `input.epoch_size` is actually the number of batches of the data:

```
for step in range(model.input.epoch_size):
    feed_dict = {}
    for i, (c, h) in enumerate(model.initial_state):
      feed_dict[c] = state[i].c
      feed_dict[h] = state[i].h

    vals = session.run(fetches, feed_dict)
    cost = vals["cost"]
    state = vals["final_state"]

    costs += cost
    iters += model.input.num_steps

    if verbose and step % (model.input.epoch_size // 10) == 10:
      print("%.3f perplexity: %.3f speed: %.0f wps" %
            (step * 1.0 / model.input.epoch_size, np.exp(costs / iters),
             iters * model.input.batch_size / (time.time() - start_time)))
```

But I wonder, how does this code "tell" the LSTM model in which epoch we are? In the LSTM class just in the init method the whole data was loaded and the computation is defined generally on the data.

My second question is the feeding of `c` and `h` to the computation. Why do we do that? Does it have something to  do with stateful vs stateless LSTM? So could I remove that code safely for a vanilla LSTM?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your first question, do leave a comment in case I've misinterpreted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see [line 348](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L348) in the same file, the code is calling `run_epoch()` once for each epoch. Each epoch, the LSTM cell is initialized to an all zero state as the training proceeds.  Coming to your questions,

> But I wonder, how does this code "tell" the LSTM model in which epoch we are? In the LSTM class just in the init method the whole data was loaded and the computation is defined generally on the data.

The weights inside the LSTM cell are being updated and at the beginning of each epoch the `initial_state` of the LSTM is used. There is no need to explicitely tell the LSTM the epoch number.

> My second question is the feeding of c and h to the computation. Why do we do that? Does it have something to do with stateful vs stateless LSTM? So could I remove that code safely for a vanilla LSTM?

This is a very important step. This is done to pass the LSTM state across various batches. An LSTM has two internal states, `c` and `h`. When these are fed to the graph, the previous batch's final state becomes the initial state for the next batch. You can replace this by just calculating `model.final_state` and passing it the next time in `feed_dict`. If you look at the TensorFlow code, `state` is essentially a tuple of `c` and `h` when `state_is_tuple` is `True`, as you can read [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4172ca2cd7ac34be67bda2600944d284e8907b95/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L260).

Comment: One more thing, the `for` loop was used in the tutorial to feed variables to all the layers of the network. To the best of my knowledge, this is not needed, you can directly pass `state`, which is a tuple of `LSTMStateTuple`

Answer (score 0):

```
# for i, (c, h) in enumerate(model.initial_state):
#   feed_dict[c] = state[i].c
#   feed_dict[h] = state[i].h

feed_dict[model._initial_state]=state;
```

For loop is to initial the first cell state of current batch with the final cell state of last batch.